# Why does http.NotFound() take the request as an argument?

Tags: go

The `http.NotFound()` method has [the following signature](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NotFound):

```
func NotFound(w ResponseWriter, r *Request)
```

What is/was the purpose of the `*Request` argument?

Currently the value seems to be unused, and I find it hard to imagine what it might have been used for in the past.

Comment: If you meant to ask: Why does it take a _request_ as an argument: Because all standard HTTP handlers take a request as the argument. If it had a different signature, it couldn't interoperate with other standard tools such as [this](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NotFoundHandler). And having the request for such a handler could be useful, if you want to examine the `Accept:` header, for instance.

Comment: So that it can be used as a [HandlerFunc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This signature is the standard `http.Handler` signature.

NotFound obviously does not use the request:

```
// NotFound replies to the request with an HTTP 404 not found error.
func NotFound(w ResponseWriter, r *Request) { Error(w, "404 page not found", StatusNotFound) }
```

However, by sticking to the standard interface it interoperates with the rest of the http package:

```
http.HandleFunc("/favicon.ico", http.NotFound)
```

Comment: And it allows for people to use the request in their own code, for instance if the 404 also needs to report the original request URL, which can be useful if you're debugging across 302/307 redirects.